# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF' for table-valued function

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, if-statement

I'm trying to create a table-valued function, which takes two parameters, "ThreadID" and "UserID", and then returns a table with two values, "HasVoted" and "IsUpvote".

```
CREATE FUNCTION HasVotedIsUpvote
(   
    @ThreadID int,
    @UserID int
)

RETURNS @returnTable TABLE 
(
    HasVoted int NOT NULL,
    IsUpvote int NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN 

DECLARE @HasVoted bit
DECLARE @IsUpvote bit


SELECT @HasVoted =
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT tv.IsUpvote
    FROM dbo.ThreadVotes as tv
    WHERE tv.ThreadID = @ThreadID
    AND tv.UserID = @UserID)
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)

IF @HasVoted = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT @IsUpvote =
    (SELECT tv.IsUpvote
    FROM dbo.ThreadVotes as tv
    WHERE tv.ThreadID = @ThreadID
    AND tv.UserID = @UserID)
END

BEGIN
    INSERT @returnTable
    SELECT @HasVoted, @IsUpvote
END

RETURN
END
GO
```

This to me seems like it should work, but I get the error message:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure HasVotedIsUpvote, Line 38 [Batch Start Line 4]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
```

Comment: ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)   END

Comment: Wow, that was fast, and it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This seems to be an awfully inefficient reason/implementation of a function. It's very "procedural" which is the opposite of what good SQL should be (set-based). How would this typically be used?

Comment: I admit I'm not very good at SQL. I'm using this function in a stored procedure along with 2 other functions.

Comment: It seems like you could obtain a similar level of information in the calling query by merely having a `LEFT JOIN` to the `ThreadVotes` table.

Answer (score 2):

Your `CASE` expression seems to be missing an `END`:

```
SELECT @HasVoted =
    CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT tv.IsUpvote
                    FROM dbo.ThreadVotes as tv
                    WHERE tv.ThreadID = @ThreadID
                          AND tv.UserID = @UserID)
          THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
       ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END -- Should be used here
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing END keyword in

```
SELECT @HasVoted =
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT tv.IsUpvote
    FROM dbo.ThreadVotes as tv
    WHERE tv.ThreadID = @ThreadID
    AND tv.UserID = @UserID)
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
    END  // <-- This one
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

An inline table valued- UDF cannot contain ANY statements other than a single Select Statement. It has to be possible to fold the logic in the UDF into whatever external SQL statement you use it in, so that the combined SQL can be processed by the query processor and stored in process cache as a combined compiled process.  What you wrote is not an inline table-valued UDF. It is an ordinary procedural UDF (coded to return a table variable), which will be re-compiled every time it is executed.

AN inline Table-valued UDF, otoh, is only compiled once, because the SQL in it is combined with the SQL of the statement or procedure where it is used, to make a single combined SQL statement which is compiled once, stored in procedure cache and used over and over again.

try this:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION HasVotedIsUpvote   
 ( @ThreadID int, @UserID int )
 RETURNS TABLE 
 AS
 return 
   (Select count(*) hasVoted, 
      Sum(isUpvote) isUpvote
    from ThreadVotes
    where ThreadID = @ThreadID
       and UserID = @UserID )
```

Comment: There are two types of table-valued UDFs - inline and multistatement. Your assertion ("cannot contain ANY statemnents other than a single Select Statement.") is true for inline but (hopefully obviously from the name) untrue for multistatement.

Comment: Yes, @Damian, you caught me in edit mode.  I hate it that I cannot, while writing them, lock my answers from being displayed until I am finished.  The complete thought never comes perfectly out of my fingers the first time.